# Cant figure out correct loop

Tags: python, selenium

I need help reiterating this when it does not occur, and for it to loop until it happens. I need it to do this

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[.//a[contains(.,'Red')]][.//a[.='Dark Green']]//a")`

and if it does not happen then I need it to do again until it happens.

```
driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts")
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[.//a[contains(.,'Red')]] 
[.//a[.='Dark Green']]//a")
while True:
time.sleep(1.2)
if items:
   items[0].click()
   break
else:
    driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts")
```

Comment: What is your scenario? Can you describe the sequence of actions you want to execute?

Comment: I am in need of having it to look for specific items on the page and when that item is found i need it to click that item. and if the item is not there i need it to refresh the page after set amount of time and on each refresh of the page, i need it to look for that same item. @Andersson

Comment: Please correctly transcribe your indentation. It matters in python. The code you have posted will not run in its current form.

Comment: So you want your script to continuously search for the same element until found? Which element exactly?

Comment: The elements are red and dark green in this one @Andersson

Comment: So... You need to locate both *red* and *dark green* items right? If at least one is absent - refresh page? Like that?

Comment: Is this script going to be running for hours or something? You should be able to add a simple WebDriverWait for the element to be clickable and then click it.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium, I would use WebDriverWait.until to wait until the elements load, rather than checking iteratively:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elements = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath('the_xpath'))
```

The docs (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) might also be really helpful.

Comment: This might work but then when that element shows up I need it to click that item. @darshvader